Why does using nested loops cause the program to freeze?
I was trying to run the WDT on a specific microcontroller (it's still under development, and I accidentally got it as a test sample) and encountered an issue where, to start the WDT, there needs to be a delay between initialization and the WDT starting. There are no standard functions for this, so I wrote simple nested loops.
What I expect from it is the following:

after initializing the peripherals,
the green LED turns on (indicating that the functions have worked),
then a delay occurs,
the green LED turns off,
the WDT starts, and
the red LED turns on in an infinite loop.
Then the WDT completes the countdown, resets the controller, and everything starts over.

And it actually works like that!
However, I decided to change i = 2, expecting no significant changes
(after the first while(i--), j remains 0, which I understood during experiments),
and the delay time should change by some number of clock cycles, which should be unnoticed by me, and I should still observe the blinking of both LEDs.
But the green LED does not turn off, and the red LED does not turn on.
Can you tell me what might be the problem? Is it related to the C language, the compiler, or specific to the microcontroller?
Here is the code:
int main()
{
    volatile uint32_t i=1;
    volatile uint32_t j=1000000;;

    setup();
    GREEN_LED_OFF();
    RED_LED_OFF();
    WDT_Init();
    GREEN_LED_ON();
    while(i--)
    {
        while(j--)
        {

        }
    }
    GREEN_LED_OFF();
    HAL_WDT_Start(&hwdt, 100);
    while(1)
    {
        RED_LED_ON();
    }
}


j doesn't remain at 0. The loop exits when j is 0, but is immediately decremented to -1 (wrapping around to 2^32-1, which is not a falsey value.

I suggest to use for loops for this type of counting like for(j = 1000000; j != 0; j--). This would avoid several problems/misunderstandings in your code.

@TedKleinBergman I assumed that after the first while(i--), j would remain 0, since the variable is not redefined. Doesn't uint32_t prevent the variable from becoming negative?

@Bodo Thank you! I did that afterward. But it's interesting to figure out this issue.

@bodo - it is guaranteed bu the standard for not signed types.

The correct way for using nested while loops would be to add j=1000000; after while(j--) { }. Or if you want j to remain 0, use while(j) { j--; }. The value will wrap-around from 0 to the biggest possible value. See onlinegdb.com/t8ZdSovij  (I confused the wrap-around behavior of signed and unsigned types in my previous, now deleted comment.)

What you describe isn't sensible use of a WDT. You need to enable it asap and then if needed, kick on it multiple times during initialization, then just kick it once at the top of the for(;;) loop in main.

When you change i to 2 after the first loop j is not 0 but UINT32_MAX as j is being decremented after the test, which is 4'294'967'295. If you have 80MHz clock and your loop is executed in 10clock cycles (volatile and -O3) then it will take 42'949'672'950 clock cycles to go through your loop.
It will take about 536 seconds if your code is executed from SRAM with 0 wait states. If you execute from FLASH it will take longer.
If you do not enable optimizations then this loop will run much longer
Demo:
int main(void)
{
    volatile unsigned i = 1;
    volatile unsigned j = 1000000;

    while(i--)
    {
        while(j--)
        {

        }
        printf("j = %u\n", j);
    }
}

https://godbolt.org/z/8P8f83ssf
if you change to while(--j) then decrementing will happen before test and j will be 0 after the test

Yes, exactly! Thank you, I focused on the fact that uint cannot become negative, but completely forgot that it can still change its value after 0.
